# How to create table with dynamically rows and columns with number of fields in template Django

Tags: python, django

I want to create dynamically rows and columns table in Django with number. Like the attached picture below

```
<table border="1">
                    {% for i in row %}
                        <tr>
                            {% for x in columns %}
                                <td>????</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your picture that you want to have 3 columns and n rows, you can do it with splitting your list into sublist with 3 elements.

Do this in your views.py:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  
n = 3 #elements per sublist
  
final_list = [my_list[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(my_list) + n - 1) // n )]
```

Make sure that you are passing the final_list to your template.

In the template you can iterate over the list and build your table like:

```
<table>
  {% for sublist in final_list %}
    <tr>
      {% for element in sublist %}
        <td>element</td> 
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but what if my rows and columns values ​​are dynamically generated. like this : 
'rows': range(0,5),
 'columns': range(0,7),